# Login again after profile update

Tags: login, profiles

I am trying to update user profile from front. On submit of the profile form this is my php code:

```
wp_set_password( $password, $user_ID );
wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_ID, 'user_email' => $email ) );

wp_cache_delete($user_ID, 'users');
wp_cache_delete($username, 'userlogins');
wp_logout();

$cred = array('user_login' => $username, 'user_password' => $password, 'remember' => true);
$user = wp_signon($cred, false);
wp_redirect( '/resultater/?profile' );
exit;
```

But it is not working. It redirects me here '/resultater/?login=failed'. I have tried the wp_signon function in other places to check, and it works. I just want the user to log in back after he updates his profile. How can I do that?